# Here is the error stack: TypeError: XXX_1.Foo is not a constructor, as runtime (compiles fine)

Tags: typescript, webpack, vscode-extensions, commonjs

I am writing a VS Code Extension in TypeScript, and I'm trying to export a class for use in other TS files. I've been able to export functions and interfaces just fine, however when I try to export a class to another TS file, it breaks with the error:

```
Here is the error stack:  TypeError: extension_1.Foo is not a constructor
```

Where the class is `Foo` in `extension.js`.

It's worth noting that this all compiles fine, but I get this error at RUNTIME.

My class is very simple:

```
export class Foo {
    constructor() {}
    public getValues(keys: string[] | undefined): string[] { return []; }
}
```

and I import it as you normally would:

```
import { Foo } from "../extension";
```

and instantiate as

```
let foo = new Foo();
```

My `tsconfig.json` looks like

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6",
        "outDir": "out",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strict": true,
        "rootDir": "src",
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        ".vscode-test"
    ]
}
```

Im using webpack w/ ts-loader, with devDependencies:

```
 "devDependencies": {
        "@types/node": "^10.12.18",
        "@types/vscode": "^1.32.0",
        "ts-loader": "^6.0.4",
        "tslint": "^5.16.0",
        "typescript": "^3.5.1",
        "webpack": "^4.35.2",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.5",
        "vscode": "^1.1.34"
    }
```

I'm quite perplexed as to what's going on!

Comment: I can't reproduce that error in my projects, but I have a couple of things that may resolve this: 1. Remove the constructor if it does nothing. 2. Mark the constructor as public. 3. Are you certain you are importing from the correct module?

Comment: @JakeSidSmith see my answer below; I seemed to have figured it out. Also, I wasn't using modules/namespaces at all.

Comment: Ah, I have encountered this problem myself in the past, but since started using a circular dependency checker in my builds. It may have been my next question following "Are you certain you're importing from the correct module?". Glad you've resolved it. :) P.s. If you are using imports and exports then you are using modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I appears my problem was I had a circular dependency!

A simplified version of my `shared-data.ts` looked like:

```
import { SHARED_DATA_1 } from './shared-data-1.ts'

export class Foo {
   constructor(..) { };
   getValues(): string[] { ... };
}

export const SHARED_OBJ = { 
  key0: { 
     data1: 'hello world',
     data2: new Foo(..)
  },
  key1: SHARED_DATA_1,
  key2: SHARED_DATA_2
}
```

`shared-data-1.ts` looked like:

```
import { Foo } from './shared-data.ts'
export const SHARED_DATA_1 = {
   data-1: new Foo()
}
```

Once I moved Foo out into its own file `./Foo.ts`, and updated both `shared-data.ts` and `shared-data-1.ts` to `import { Foo } from './Foo.ts'` everything worked just fine.

My actual dependency chain is a bit more complex, but this is a simplification and explains the crux of the matter.